# Sum of each specific columns of total subset in R

Tags: r

I just started to learn R and I would like to use it in simulation of options pricing.
I wrote a function to create 1000 data.frames as below. 
I'd like to get mean of "yBaseCcy" at each "Period" t, anyway to do this?

```
[[9]]
  Period ccyPairs        x    K     P        IV yBaseCcy yTermCcy LyBaseCcy
1      1   USDZAR 13.03787 12.8 0e+00 0.0000000     0.00      0.0         0
2      2   USDZAR 12.52903 12.8 1e+06 0.2709659 21627.04 270965.9         0

[[10]]
  Period ccyPairs        x    K     P        IV yBaseCcy yTermCcy LyBaseCcy
1      1   USDZAR 12.09013 12.8 0e+00 0.7098709        0        0         0
2      2   USDZAR 12.01183 12.8 1e+06 0.0000000        0        0         0
```

Comment: Can you also show the expected output from this sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all data frames have identical structure (the same number of rows, where each row is for the same period), then you can extract the vector of interest from each one, add them all up, and divide by the total number:

```
Reduce("+", lapply(dat, function(x) x$yBaseCcy)) / length(dat)
# [1] 3 4
```

Sample data:

```
(dat <- list(data.frame(Period=1:2, yBaseCcy=1:2), data.frame(Period=1:2, yBaseCcy=3:4), data.frame(Period=1:2, yBaseCcy=5:6)))
# [[1]]
#   Period yBaseCcy
# 1      1        1
# 2      2        2
# 
# [[2]]
#   Period yBaseCcy
# 1      1        3
# 2      2        4
# 
# [[3]]
#   Period yBaseCcy
# 1      1        5
# 2      2        6
```

Comment: Thanks for the example and I find it useful for applying higher order functions!